# How can I inherit from a function without bollocksing the ability to use the 'name' property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype-chain

In javascript, it seems like if an object inherits from a function, it simply can't use the name property. I've tested this in node.js, and its likely true in various browsers. E.g.:

```
var A = function() {}
    A.prototype = function() {}

var x = new A()
x.name = "bob"
console.log(x.name) // logs blank
```

It seems almost absurd that you can't override properties given in an objects prototype (ie `__proto__`) in this case. Am I going crazy?

Comment: Why do you want to assign a function to `A.prototype`?

Comment: Because I'm writing an inheritance module, and being able to do this would make it a little less warty (right now properties like 'name' and 'caller' can't be accessed as static properties using my module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't because of the function but because there is a [descriptor
in the prototype](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.4) for that name with `writable` `false`. `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(function(){}, "name").writable === false`

If you create a described unwritable property normally, the same happens too:

```
function A() {

}

Object.defineProperty( A.prototype, "name", {
    value: ""
});

var a = new A()

a.name
//""
a.name = "bob"
//"bob"
a.name
//""
```

You need to go through the `Object.defineProperty` to do it:

```
Object.defineProperty(x, "name", {value: "bob"})
x.name
//"bob"
```

Comment: Good info, but I'd still consider that a bit broken - since it'll almost certainly bite the uninitiated. I'm going to hold out a little while for a magical cureall.

Comment: @BT Well it is what it is, many things in JS will bite the uninitiated but the language just cannot easily have backwards compatibility breaking changes. I guess not many applications would be broken by fixing this but I can't be sure. Also it could be by delibarate design, e.g. having writability of property names described in the prototype instead on every separate instance could be desirable. Also it makes no sense to have function as a prototype since the methods are hard-wired to only work on actual functions as receivers.

Comment: Good points. But I think using a function as a prototype makes a lot of sense - maybe just not in javascript ; )

Comment: Well what sense does it make? And if you admit it doesn't make any sense in Javascript, why the question.

Comment: I'm admitting the possibility, not the truth of that. It makes a whole lot of sense if using a function as a prototype meant that your object could be used like a function. Would make for some interesting constructs. Also, I made an inheritance function that omits the new operator while still allowing inheritance. If I were able to use the resulting functions as prototypes, it would make this library much cleaner.

Comment: But that is not the case (The object doesn't become callable) as you must have immediately noticed even before making the question.

Comment: You're really not hearing me. In my comment, I'm talking about the concept of inheritance, not inheritance shoehorned into javascript. Its certainly possible for a language to define inheritance in such a way that an object does in fact inherit callability.